# SAPUI5: i18n property content in html tags within xml views

Tags: html, xml, view, internationalization, sapui5

How to include i18n property content in html tags within xml views, i.e. 
a "normal" text tag in the xml view would look like this:

```
<Text text="Lorem ipsum"/>
```

with i18n property e.g.:

```
<Text text="{i18n>LOREMIPSUM}"/>
```

How to include the "{i18n>LOREMIPSUM}" for ?

```
<html:p> </html:p>
```

Thanks

Comment: why would you work with an html-tag inside an XML view?!

Comment: @zyrex Don't you think there is a reason why html tags are supported in sapui5 xml views?

Comment: @zyrex: check this out: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.core.HTML/samples

Comment: whats the usecase, thats my question.

Comment: well, in my case, I have already plenty of html code which wants to be transfered to xml views (xml views because that's the standard and they're better manageable as other view type). Plus: I'd be interested in seeing an easier and better manageable way of how to create e.g. a ul/ol etc. in SAPUI5 xml views with xml (instead of html)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your XML view...

```
<HTML xmlns="sap.ui.core" content="{i18n>myHtmlContent}" />
```

and something like this in your i18n.properties...

```
myHtmlContent=<p>This is an example of <b>internationalized HTML</b> text.</p>
```

It is **very** important that the HTML string is **fully** encapsulated into some outer tag (in this case `<p>...</p>`). The HTML control will NOT work correctly, if it contains any text outside of tags.

The beauty of this approach is, that you do not have to escape any special characters in HTML. Escaping would in fact be necessary, if you would place the HTML directly into the content attribute in XML. Placing it in i18n.properties instead makes the whole HTML content a lot easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use core:html tag to add HTML . I am not sure how to bind it to html:p . But, the following code works.

```
<core:HTML
 content='&lt;div &gt;{i18n&gt;LOREMIPSUM}&lt;/div&gt;'>
</core:HTML>
```

Comment: unfortunately, following two do not work:  <html:p content="{i18n>LOREMIPSUM}"></html:p> 
    <html:p content="&lt;div &gt;{i18n&gt;LOREMIPSUM}&lt;/div&gt;"></html:p>

Comment: @ksc just use core:html tag (no the html:p tag) as in my answer and add your HTML code inside content of core:html tag. this is working for me.

Comment: Without having tried it out, I can say that this (at first sight) would not fulfill my requirements since it goes beyond - not only p tags are affected, also and especially li within ul/ol and others, unless I can somehow nest this core html in these various tags (which would make it quite complicated, right? Isn't there a quick and easy solution to this?). I have loads of html tags within xml views and want to basically "outsource" the content to i18n property files.

Comment: @ksc you can use HTML views and embed in xml views or use [Handlebars](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/58/a8e2deb5954cc79fcc81841b2e13aa/content.htm?frameset=/en/31/2c097c9c7e4df58eee1f121c5490b4/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/e4/843b8c3d05411c83f58033bac7f072/plain.htm&node_id=362)

Comment: Hi stpc, can you please help on these handlebars since I'm not familiar with that. From the link you posted, I see these examples with reference to i18n content: {{element tag="div" text="{i18n>MY_TEXT}"}} or {{text path="i18n>MY_TEXT"}} I played a bit around, but still, how would I include this example here: <html:p> </html:p> or here <html:li> </html:li>. This does not work for me: <html:li> {{text path="i18n>MY_TEXT"}}</html:li>  thx